# How do I validate a radio button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, colors

How do I validate a radio button? I want to make it so that if the user left the radio button unclicked the section background will turn a red colour/color.

Here is the HTML Page

```
<p id="caption_project">Project Selection
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="f__project" id="in_restaurant" value="restaurant"/>
    <label for="in_restaurant">LEGO Project</label>
    <br/>

    <input type="radio" name="f__project" id="in_humber" value="Humber News"/>
    <label for="in_humber">Humber Current Project</label>
                        <br/>

    <input type="radio" name="f__project" id="in_self" value="self-determined"/>
    <label for="in_self">Self-determined Project</label>
</p>
```

So how do I turn the background red when they leave it unchecked?

Comment: Please show some kind of javascript attempt and a button in your html to trigger the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of some event the user will fire which you want to trigger the function that makes the background go red. That could be if the user clicks on the next form control. Then when that event fires you test whether they checked any radio buttons. If they did not (`!checked`) then you set the style attribute of your p element to background:red:

```js
const nextThing = document.querySelector('#next-thing');

const p = document.querySelector('p');

nextThing.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const checked = document.querySelector("input[name='f__project']:checked");
  if(!checked){
    p.setAttribute('style', 'background:red');
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="caption_project">Project Selection
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="f__project" id="in_restaurant" value="restaurant"/>
  <label for="in_restaurant">LEGO Project</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="f__project" id="in_humber" value="Humber News"/>
  <label for="in_humber">Humber Current Project</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="f__project" id="in_self" value="self-determined"/>
  <label for="in_self">Self-determined Project</label>
</p>

<button id='next-thing'>Next form control</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelector("input[name='f__project']:checked")`. If this returns `null`, none of the radio buttons were checked, and you can display the red background.

If this is in a `<form>` you can add the `required` attribute to the radio buttons. If they try to submit the form without selecting one of them, the browser will display a validation error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementById('id').checked`the statement returns True or False.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const checkedRadioButton = document.
   querySelector("input[name='f__project']:checked");

if (!checkedRadioButton) {
  // No values are selected
} else {
  // Some value is selected and the element is stored in checkedRadioButton
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to manipulate the colour depending on whether the radio input is checked or not.

```
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
  border: 5px solid lightblue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

Or else you can make a Javascript function to check

```
function checkRadioValidity() { 
            if(document.getElementById('in_restaurant').checked) {
                //change CSS here for the element
            }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea of radio button is that it can not be unchecked.

EDIT:

```
document.querySelector("input[name='f__project']:checked")
```

will return element if it is checked

Comment: They're all unchecked before you select one of them.

Comment: Ya, in my HTML page there is a submit button, and I wanted it to be if the user forgot to check one it won't submit and the background of that section turns red.

Comment: so you should provide default value. what is the point to leave it unchecked if user must check one of it?

Comment: Because you want to force them to choose. Suppose it's an age radio button, why would you have a default value?

Comment: @Barmar "The main guideline for radio button design is to select one of the radio buttons by default (i.e., when the page loads" :)

Comment: BTW, I edited answer @DanyalChatha

Comment: @Georgemff Where is that from? It makes no sese. If you have a male/female radio button, why would either of them be the default?